# bash print multiline variable, but also use it as a command for python?

Tags: python, bash, arguments, echo, newline

I want to create a variable that is human readable with bash, but then also be able to run the variable as a python script.

```
run_cmd(){
        echo "[+] Creating stuff"
        run_command="$script 10.10.10.10 \\
        --config $settings \\
        --cid $cid \\
        -v"
    echo -e "$run_comamnd"
    $run_command
}

run_cmd
```

Running the above will print out the following

```
[+] Creating stuff
pythonscript 10.10.10.10 \
        --config $settings \
        --cid $cid \
        -v"

usage: pythonscript [-v] --cid CID --config CONFIG host
pythonscript: error: unrecognized arguments \ \ \
```

If I remove the `\\` and just have `\` like the following, the command runs but the output removes all of the new line chars.

```
run_cmd(){
        echo "[+] Creating stuff"
        run_command="$script 10.10.10.10 \
        --config $settings \
        --cid $cid \
        -v"
    echo -e "$run_comamnd"
    $run_command
}

run_cmd
```

Output

```
[+] Creating stuff
pythonscript 10.10.10.10         --config $settings         --cid $cid         -v"
[+] this output is from pythonscript, the script ran successfully.
```

I know that if I remove `\` entirely from the variable, it will print out new lines and run the command. However I want the `\` so someone can copy the command that is outputted and run directly from command line, so I need the `\` on output.

How can I have my cake and eat it too? As in print out the command with new lines, and also run it, without having to make seperate variables for the echo statement and the run statement?

Comment: See [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). It explicitly discusses your [use case](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I_want_a_log_of_my_script.27s_actions).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a variable that is human readable with bash, but then also be able to run the variable as a python script.

Best advice: [Don't.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

**variables hold data; functions hold code.**

Also, nothing in your example seems likely to *need* linebreaks...

Based on what you showed, here's a POC rewrite -

```
run_cmd() {
  local rc prog ip id cfg                                       # protect possible globals
  if (($#))                                                     # were args passed in?
  then prog="$1" ip="$2" id="$3" cfg="$4"                       # assign to local analogs
  else prog="$script" ip=10.10.10.10 id="$cid" cfg="$settings"; # else use global defaults
  fi
  echo "[+] Creating stuff"                                     # whatever pre-run steps you want
  set -x                                                        # show what's actually executing
  "$prog" "$ip" --config "$cfg" --cid "$id" -v; rc=$?           # execute; self-logs.
  { set +x; } 2>&-                                              # *silently* turn off debug output
  return $rc                                                    # function returns script result
}
```

In use:

```
$: echo "script=[$script] cid=[$cid] settings=[$settings]"
script=[echo] cid=[123] settings=[a=1 b=2]

$: run_cmd
[+] Creating stuff
+ echo 10.10.10.10 --config 'a=1 b=2' --cid 123 -v
10.10.10.10 --config a=1 b=2 --cid 123 -v
+ rc=0

$: run_cmd : 1.2.3.4 fatboy "x=42 y=9999 z=xmp"
[+] Creating stuff
+ : 1.2.3.4 --config 'x=42 y=9999 z=xmp' --cid fatboy -v
+ rc=0

$: run_cmd : 1.2.3.4 me x=123,y=999,z=other
[+] Creating stuff
+ : 1.2.3.4 --config x=123,y=999,z=other --cid me -v
+ rc=0

$: run_cmd : 1.2.3.4 fatboy "whatever your settings string is"
[+] Creating stuff
+ : 1.2.3.4 --config 'whatever your settings string is' --cid fatboy -v
+ rc=0
```

What I have done:

First, I broke out the data/parameters to their own vars, but the *code*/execution is set in the function.

Second, I accept args, or use defaults, but with all-or-none logic to keep it simple.

Third, I rely on the interpreter's debugging to show what gets executed.

As an addendum, notice that I also turn *off* the debugging output after collecting the return code, and throw away the debug reporting of doing so to reduce noise. YMMV.